# Check the '...\HiQPdf.dep' resource file can be found near the HiQPdf.dll assembly and the user has read and execute permissions for this file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdf, shared-hosting

I am using HiQPdf plugin to convert a page (a customer invoice) to pdf on ASP.NET MVC app. It works fine on localhost but throws error after I publish it to Godaddy shared hosting server. This is the error it throws:

> Error 0x4EC. Check the 'G:**\domain.com\Content\HiQPdf.dep' resource file can be found near the HiQPdf.dll assembly and the user has read and execute permissions for this file. Call SetDepFilePath() method if you placed the HiQPdf.dep in a different location

I have been searching since yesterday with no avail, I have confirmed that the HiQPdf.dep exist in Content folder, these are what I've tried and all worked locally but none solved the issue on GoDaddy:

1. Copied the HiQPdf.dep to Content folder and used the SetDepFilePath() method to refer to it.

   // init model
   var model = _db.Invoice.Where(x => x.InvoiceId == invoiceId && !x.Draft)
   .ToArray().Select(x => new InvoiceVM(x)).FirstOrDefault();

   ```
       // convert a page to string (update the path to the right page)
       string html = RenderViewToString(ControllerContext, "~/views/home/_InvoiceDoc.cshtml", model);

       // start creating pdf doc
       // the base URL to resolve relative images and css
       string thisPageUrl = this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
       string baseUrl = thisPageUrl.Substring(0, thisPageUrl.Length -"Home/ConvertThisPageToPdf".Length);

       // instantiate the HiQPdf HTML to PDF converter
       HtmlToPdf htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdf();

       htmlToPdfConverter.SetDepFilePath(Server.MapPath("~/Content/HiQPdf.dep"));

       // render the HTML code as PDF in memory
       byte[] pdfBuffer = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertHtmlToMemory(html, baseUrl);

       // send the PDF file to browser
       FileResult fileResult = new FileContentResult(pdfBuffer, "application/pdf");
       fileResult.FileDownloadName = "Invoice-" + model.InvoiceNumber + ".pdf";

       return fileResult;
   ```
2. I changed permissions for both the HiQPdf.dep file and Content folder on GoDaddy to full control, didn't work too.
3. I have set the trust level to Full in the web.config, still solving the issue.

> 